# Guest have no connectivity (qemu-kvm, user mode)

Tags: debian, networking, kvm

I use Debian Jessie on my host machine. And the same version on guest.
I want to use user mode networking with qemu-kvm.
I experienced no connectivity, i. e. `wget www.google.com` returned no connection. I am surprised, because `dedian-installer` can reach internet resources during installation process (i installed Debian Jessie on guest machine from `netinst` image).

Qemu command:

```
/usr/bin/kvm -monitor stdio \
             -smp 2 -cpu kvm32 -enable-kvm -m 512\
             -soundhw ac97 \
             -vga std \
             -drive file="image.qcow2",cache=writeback,aio=threads \
             -boot once=c,menu=off \
             -net nic,vlan=0 -net user,vlan=0 \
             -no-quit -name "boot"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you installed from `netinst`, did you start kvm with same parameters?

Comment: Yes. Except boot device priority and cd-rom image.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the problem caused by ipv6-networking. Host system have no ipv6 access, so on the guest side i can not get access to ipv4 network by ipv6 protocols.

So i turned ipv6 support off by passing corresponding option to the kernel. I added to `/etc/default/grub` this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
```